# How to upload Laravel 5.1 project on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have developed project in Laravel 5.1 framework and it is working on my localhost.

Now I want to upload it into my shared hosting account. I tried to upload all files in public html folder of server but still the project was not accessible. It shows blank not single error also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the tutorial at the following link, it helped me.

https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd

If you face problem in any specific step, please comment on this answer.