# Laravel 5.2 - how to upload laravel app to shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, shared-hosting

how to upload laravel app to eHost hosting service after developing on localhost ?

Comment: Have you tried to search for an answer already? Probably a few people have asked this question and found an answer. Try Google or SO first - then come back here with things you've tried and problems you've encountered and overcome

Comment: yes I did.. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514806/how-to-upload-laravel-5-1-project-on-shared-hosting) and [here](https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd#.p982grg4e) .. and many have almost same answer .. but I didn't get exactly how to do this .. I'm new .. to both laravel and shared hosting .. specially shared hosting it's my first time and I'm using ehost,, domain reserved already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to put Laravel on a shared hosting is to have **SSH access**, **Git** and **Composer** install. Create a symboly link

Comment: I now uploaded it successfully .. but how use ssh access to upload my files ?

Comment: you can just use you FTP access to upload the file to your server, without the vendor directory